# Can I combine two "consecutive" tickets on the same journey without leaving the train?

Tags: uk, tickets, national-rail, trainline

I booked off-peak return tickets from London to Oxford. Unfortunately I mis-tapped in the Trainline app and accidentally bought tickets to *Oxford Parkway* rather than *Oxford* (the main station). *Parkway* is the station directly before it.

I could get a refund on the tickets and buy correct tickets; however, Trainline charges a 10 GBP fee in this case.

I’m wondering whether I could just buy a cheap return ticket Oxford Parkway–Oxford instead, and combine the two legs of the journey (London Marylebone–Oxford Parkway, Oxford Parkway–Oxford … and vice-versa on the return) into one, without having to leave the train (or the station) at Oxford Parkway.

In case that changes anything, the tickets were bought using a *Two Together Railcard*.

Comment: Why would you be required to leave the train or the station?

Comment: @Kyralessa To tap in/out at the station. I’ve had trouble previously with tickets where the start/destination didn’t correspond with what it said on the ticket, even though I effectively travelled only what was allowed on the ticket. Intuitively I agree with you: this *should* be fine.

Comment: If there are automated barriers, there is always an attendant to let people through, for example someone with a stroller or wheelchair. With a valid ticket there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: When two stations are close together, the railroads often consider them the same for fare purposes.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica This is actually pretty rare in the UK. You can often get a ticket to "London Terminus Stations". Also, you can get "Reading or Reading West". But these are actually the only ones that come to my mind. The "Parkway" stations are also normally not that close to the centre---not really far, but not close. Both Cambridge and Cambridge North are in the town but you don't get an "or" ticket

Comment: Similar to: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/114769/in-germany-can-you-take-a-non-stop-train-if-you-have-tickets-for-individual-sta

Comment: @Sam OT There is a a Wikipedia page which shows 38 such groups: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Station_group_(railway)#Existing_groups

Comment: @skifans An excellent resource, thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes you can do this - as long as the train stops at the intermediate station there is no need to physically get on/off the train. You can buy tickets between any combinations of stations from any station, so you can buy the tickets at London station before leaving.

I've personally done this loads of times, but the relevant section in [the conditions of travel](https://www.nationalrail.co.uk/National%20Rail%20Conditions%20of%20Travel.pdf) is:

> 14.1. Unless shown below, you may use a combination of two or more Tickets to make a journey provided that the train services you use
> call at the station(s) where you change from one Ticket to another.

---

However, there may be a cheaper & better option. You could instead an overdistance excess fare, this "changes" your existing ticket. Information on these can be found [here](https://internal.nationalrail.co.uk/187064.aspx#DESTINATION) (assuming you are at a ticket office before traveling)

> a customer travelling beyond the destination of the ticket will be required to pay an Excess fare for the difference in price between the ticket held and the appropriate Single or Return fare, available for immediate travel, for the complete journey from the originating station to the final destination

And for the price:

> the difference between the fare paid and the appropriate Return fare for the throughout journey. If cheaper, charge the appropriate Single fare for the extra journey.

Excess fares can only be obtained from staffed ticket office, you cannot purchase them online or from ticket machines. My personal experiences is that you may need a certain level of assertiveness/trial and error to purchase excess fare tickets as they are not commonly issued. You are likely to face an additional problems if your existing ticket is anything but an orange slip of card. Excess fares can be optioned for any ticket type in theory but it posses additional problems as e/m tickets do not have a ticket number - staff usually enter 12345 in my experience but others are unwilling to do so. Note that an excess fare ticket comes as an additional slip of paper, make sure you keep both at all times as it is only valid with the original ticket. In my experience excess fare tickets do not work any ticket barriers, you will likely need to find a member of staff to let you out/in at Oxford. Although your original ticket will work the barriers fine in London. While it will be harder to obtain an excess fare it does mean that your train no longer needs to stop at Oxford Parkway, so you will additionally be able to use the faster GWR trains.

Comment: See also: [*Why is there a ticket office after the ticket barrier?*](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/68458/2509)

Answer (score 3):

No need to leave train. Just tap out with your other ticket at the exit. As long as you have a valid ticket (or tickets) for the entire length of your journey it doesn't matter.

Comment: If I'm reading the OP correctly, they want to travel from A to Z, but they accidentally bought a ticket from A to X. Unless they already have another ticket that covers X-Z, then they can't do this (possibly a season ticket)

Comment: @CSM OP specifically says they want to buy X-Z and then combine A-X + X-Z to get A-Z.

Comment: If the train does not actually stop a X then the ticket is not valid. If it does stop a X then it is perfectly fine to buy X-Z and travel A-Z. This is a good way for skipping peak ticket prices. Buy A-B peak and B-Z off peak as etc.

Answer (score -4):

You can just chance it, I've made the same mistake, explained it at the barrier and they have waved me through. Last time I checked, the price difference is 10p. Caveat Emptor...

Comment: I definitely wouldn't do this for something so easy to fix, based on the horror stories of stupid prosecutions I've heard of. Worst case is you end up going to court over 10p.

Comment: The currently accepted answer explains how to do this legally so your answer seems unhelpful.

Comment: in the UK, if you are caught you have to pay an extended fare at worst  -not having a ticket here is not illegal, its against the rules of carriage - you don't go to court, unless you do something heinous; thanks for the downvote!
https://www.lner.co.uk/customer-service/revenue-protection-policy/ "You’ve travelled beyond the destination of your ticket"

Comment: LNER does not go to Oxford, last time I checked. Also, deliberately travelling beyond the validity of a ticket is at the least liable to a penalty fare, of £20 or twice the unpaid fare, whichever is the greater. Cheaper just to 'excess' the ticket before travelling, at a ticket office.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Incidentally, only certain people have the authority to charge £20/twice. You are definitely correct that you would be liable. This comment is not disagreeing with yours, merely adding something in case you were unaware! :)